# Powering to decimal number produce wrong answer

Tags: python-3.x

My calculation is simple but it provide wrong answer,
for example `3**0.1-0.3` should equal to `0.0`,
but Python interpreter gives `0.8161`
even on using the Decimal system.

I am using python `3.6.3`, here is my code:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
print(D('3')**D('0.1')-D('0.3'))
```

output:

```
0.816123174033904434442614138
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `**` and `*`.

Try

```
print(D('3')*D('0.1')-D('0.3'))
```

Comment: yes, you are right , but mathematically (3)^0.1 - 0.3 should be 0.0 too , but it shows wrong answer in python interpretor

Comment: Fundamentally, 3 to the power of 0.1 is around 1.1. You can try and see with any of the calculators. I am guessing you're trying to get 0.3 from 3^0.1.

Comment: @MaverickTiacoon mathematically `3^0.1-0.3` **does not** equal to 0.0, please use any calculator to verify.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is right and if what you are after is powering it use the math module which you can do powering.

```
import math
print (math.pow (3,(0.1-0.3)))
```

Comment: Take the above as the below.

Comment: OP is trying to trying to power 3 to 0.1 and then minus it with 0.3

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference between 0.1 and 0.3 is minus 0.2. And since a negative exponent means resprocal of the number you could try this with out using the math module.

```
3**(1/float (-1*(0.1-0.3)))
```